# Help explain how to get $P(B'|A')$

Tags: probability, combinations

Suppose that a drawer contains $8$ marbles: $2$ are red, $2$ are blue, $2$ are green, and $2$ are yellow. The marbles are rolling around in a drawer, so that all possibilities are equally likely when they are drawn. Alice chooses $2$ marbles without replacement, and then Bob chooses $2$ marbles. Let $A$ denote the event that Alice's $2$ marbles have a matching color. Let $B$ denote the event that Bob's $2$ marbles have a matching color.

Why is $P(B'|A') = (\dfrac{2}{6})(1)+(\dfrac{4}{6})(\dfrac{4}{5})$?

Comment: Without loss of generality, let alice have picked a red and a blue marble.  We ask now, what is the probability that Bob picks two different colors from a bag of 1red, 1blue, 2green, 2yellow marbles.  If we say that Bob picks the marbles one at a time, what happens if the first marble bob picked was red or blue?  What happens if the first marble picked was green or yellow?  How often do those things happen?

Comment: Thank you. That really helped.

Answer (score 2):

To help you realize all of the different ways one could solve this, I am going to go ahead and evaluate the probabilities of each event in the universal set.

---

When Alice draws her marbles, whether her marbles are matching or not does not depend on the first draw, only on the second. After she draws the first marble, there is only one marble that matches in the remaining seven. Thus $P(A)=\frac17$ and $P(A^\prime)=\frac67$.

If $A$ occurs, then there are exactly three matching pairs left. Like with Alice, Bob’s first draw does not affect whether his marbles match. When his second draw comes around, there is $1$ matching marble in a group of $5$. Thus $P(B|A)=\frac15$ and $P(B^\prime|A)=\frac45$.

If $A^\prime$ occurs, then there are two pairs and two oddball individual marbles. The probability of Bob drawing one of the oddball marbles and making $B^\prime$ occur is $\frac13$. Thus the probability of drawing one of the balls that has a twin (“even ball” in my diagram, oops) is $\frac46$. From here, he has a $\frac15$ chance of drawing the matching twin and a $\frac45$ chance of not drawing the match. Thus $P(B^\prime|A^\prime)=\frac26+\frac46\cdot\frac45=\frac{13}{15}$ and $P(B|A^\prime)=\frac46\cdot\frac15=\frac2{15}$.

Here is the corresponding tree diagram:

[image: tree diagram]

Notice that there are two branches that lead to $A^\prime\cap B^\prime$. We add the probabilities of these branches as they are mutually exclusive.

---

We can check our answer by seeing if the probabilities of each event in the universal set add up to $1$: $$P(A\cap B)+P(A\cap B^\prime)+P(A^\prime\cap B)+P(A^\prime+B^\prime)=1$$

(They do.)

Related to this problem is [Bayes’ theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem): $$P(B|A)=\frac{P(B)\,P(A|B)}{P(A)}$$ or the variation of Bayes’ theorem derived by substituting $A$ for $A^\prime$ and $B$ for $B^\prime$, giving you $$P(B^\prime|A^\prime)=\frac{P(B^\prime)\,P(A^\prime|B^\prime)}{P(A^\prime)}$$

I would not recommend trying to use Bayes’ theorem to solve this.

Comment: That was elaborately explained. Thank you, Chase.

Comment: @GamalAl-dinSamy You're welcome! I'm covering probability in class, so it was good practice for me too! ;)

Comment: @GamalAl-dinSamy If you feel it answered your question, consider giving it the green check. It's a nice way to express appreciation, and as you use this site more, you'll get rewards for marking answers 'correct', and it helps the community know that this question has been handled adequately.